# ¿porque no realiza la consulta sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en donde se quiere lograr listar por cada uno de los materiales, todo los elementos que se encuentran en la imagen, para ello tengo dos tablas sql, al realizar la consulta aparece el error

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\reporte.php on line 81

Esta tabla se llama material
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta tabla se llama movimiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código de la consulta
En el formulario solo tengo dos input para ingresar la fecha y un botón de consultar para que muestre en una tabla todas las columnas de la imagen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        
        <script> 
            (function($) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#listar_orden_tecnico").dataTable({
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bLengthChange": true,
                        "bFilter": true,
                        "bSort": false,
                        "bScrollCollapse": true,
                        "bInfo": false,
                        "bAutoWidth": true 
                    });
                });
            })(jQuery);             
        </script> 
        
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <br>
        
        <table class="display"  border="1"  id="listar_orden_tecnico" 
                style=" background-color:  #DCDCDC; width: 70% ">
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Codigo</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Nombre</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Unidad</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. Entradas</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. Salidas</th>                    
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Precio</th>                    
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Cant. Total</th>
                    <th style=" font-size: 11px; width: 15px;">Exis. Total</th>  
                    <      
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody > 
             <tr > 
        <?php
        // put your code here
        require 'conexion.php';
        //session_start(); 
        
        $fecha_i = $_GET['fecha_i'];
        $fecha_f = $_GET['fecha_f'];
             
      
        $sql = "";
        $sql1 = "";
      
                 
        if ( $fecha_i && $fecha_f){
               

            
            

            $sql2 = " SELECT material.codigo, material.nombre_material, material.unidad, material.precio, material.cantidad, saldo.movimientos,
            SUM(IF(movimientos.tipo_movimiento = 'ENTRADA', 1, 0)),
            SUM(IF(movimientos.tipo_movimiento = 'SALIDA', 1, 0))
            FROM movimientos 
            INNER JOIN  material ON movimientos.codigo_material=material.codigo
            WhERE movimientos.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i' AND '$fecha_f'";
                            
        
           
             $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2); 
             $i=  mysqli_num_rows($result);
             
             if(!empty($result) AND mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {    
                 
                 echo "<td style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>"($rows[0])."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[1]."</td>    
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[2]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[3]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[4]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[5]."</td>
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[6]."</td>  
                       <td 'style= font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>".$rows[7]."</td>  </tr>";
                        }
                   }
                                     
                                        
                                           
           
            elseif ($i <= 0) {
                # code...
            
                echo "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>No se encontraron registros de acuerdo a la búsqueda</td> "
                . "<td style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                        . "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                        . "<td  style= 'font-size: 13px; text-align: center'>0</td> "
                     . "  </tr>";
            }                          
             
             
        }
       
             
        
       
            
        
             ?>                                
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="8">
                            
                            
                        </th> 
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entre los resultados de [esta búsqueda](/search?q=mysqli_num_rows%28%29+expects+parameter+to+be+mysqli_result%2C+given), ¿ninguna te ha dado pistas de tu problema?

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\manteniminetodeb\formularios\reporte.php on line 81

El error dice claramente.
Se espera 1 parametro de tipo mysqli_result, pero llego un booleano.
Esto quiere decir, que tu consulta SELECT falló.

Revisando tu consulta, tenemos:

```
SELECT material.codigo, material.nombre_material, material.unidad,
       material.precio, material.cantidad, saldo.movimientos
       COUNT(IF (`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA', 1, null)),
       COUNT(IF (`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento` = 'SALIDA', 1, null)),
       COUNT( * )  
       FROM moviminetos 
       INNER JOIN  materiales ON movimientos.codigo_material=material.codigo
       WhERE movimientos.fecha BETWEEN '$fecha_i' AND '$fecha_f'
```

Podemos entonces de inmediato ver, que:

- En el `FROM`, está mal escrito - "moviminetos", deberia ser "movimientos"
- El INNER JOIN es con la tabla `materiales`, pero tratas de leer `material`
- Entre `saldo.movimientos` y el primer `COUNT()`, falta una coma-
- El uso de  `COUNT` con `IF` está mal implementado.

Primero corrige esas cosas, y luego actualiza el POST.

---

Respecto al uso de `SUM()` en vez de `COUNT()`

Lo que quieres realizar es la suma de los posibles resultados que estás entregando en el IF, los cuales en este caso serán 1 si es correcto, o 0 si es correcto. Solo sumará lo correcto y retornará el dato.
Lo que quieres hacer es lo sgte:

```
SUM(IF (`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento` = 'ENTRADA', 1, 0)) as CantEntrada,
SUM(IF (`movimientos`.`tipo_movimiento` = 'SALIDA', 1, 0)) as CantSalida
```

Comment: Como seria una buena implementación del COUNT con if?, disculpa bro estoy comenzando a programar

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres es contar las filas con entrada = 1 cierto ?? ... sumalas entonces. `SUM(IF(movimientos.tipo_movimiento = 'ENTRADA', 1, 0))`

Comment: no, lo que quiero es saber cuantas entradas y salidas hay de un mismo material, por eso iba contando cuantas veces aparec la palabra ENTRADA

Comment: Entonces son dos sum como te mostraron arriba @LuisAngel

Comment: Lo pondré en la respuesta para que veas, pero el tema es que, no estás contando, estás sumando los que coincidan con ese filtro.

Comment: Actualice el código así como dice pero siempre me aparece el mismo error

Comment: @LuisAngel a la publicación, puedes añadir un var_dump() de como queda la consulta con todos los datos ??

Comment: el var_dump() a la variable de sql2?.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=listar_orden_tecnico - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 me aparece este error

Comment: Ese es un error diferente con tu datatable. Pon la consulta en la BD y revisa si funciona.

Comment: @LuisAngel trata de concentrarte en una sola pregunta a la vez XD.